# Pangram Checker in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I was wondering how to check whether a string is a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram), as a beginner's exercise. I have two solutions, but I don't understand them at all.

#### Version 1

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram str = all (`elem` map toLower str) ['a'..'z']
```

#### Version 2

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram str = allPresent (map toLower str) ['a'..'z']

allPresent :: String -> String -> Bool
allPresent _ [] = True
allPresent [] _ = False
allPresent (x:xs) ys
    | x `elem` ys = allPresent xs ys
    | otherwise = False
```

Not sure if they're correct, but any help to simplify or modify this would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, you will certainly confuse yourself if you try to understand how the second snippet is a pangram checker, because it is not one.

Answer (score 1):

Your second version is not. That should be:

```
isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram str = allPresent ['a' .. 'z'] (map toLower str)

allPresent :: String -> String -> Bool
allPresent [] _ = True
allPresent _ [] = False
allPresent (x : xs) ys
  | x `elem` ys = allPresent xs ys
  | otherwise = False
```

Indeed, for a *pangram* you check if all characters belong to the string. But that is not symmetrical: checking if all elements of *X* belong to *Y* is not equivalent to checking if all elements of *Y* belong to *X*. We here thus use the first list as the collection of items where we check if each item `x` of that collection, is an element of the second collection `ys`.

We thus call `allPresent ['a' .. 'z'] (map toLower str)` so the first list contains all lowercase characters, the second the lowercase version of the input `str`. In case the first list is empty, we are done, so we can return `True`. In case it is not, and the second list is empty, we know it will be `False`. If both lists are not empty, we check if the first item `x` of the list is a member of `ys`, and if so recurse with the rest of the elements `xs`; otherwise we can return `False`.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this without using an external module like Data.char? Also accept a list of characters, and not string? like this isPangram :: [Char] -> Bool

Comment: `String` and `[Char]` are the same, so it works already with `isPangram :: [Char] -> Bool`, `Data.Char` is not an *external* module, it is part of the `base`, and thus always "'ships" with the basic library. You could implement `toLower` yoursel with `toLower 'A' = 'a'; toLower 'a' = 'a'; toLower 'B' = 'b'`, etc.

Comment: Could you please add that to the answer above? It's hard for me to understand so I would appreciate any help

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out so! Thanks anyway!